# Envío de archivos a WebService desde un Servicio de Windows

Tags: c#, webservice, servicio

Buen día, al momento de ejecutar un .exe desde un servicio de Windows mi aplicación no hace el envío de archivos a una WebService.

Si ejecuto de forma manual el .exe si envía sin problemas los archivos. El problema es al momento de ejecutarlo desde un Servicio. No me sale ningun error al momento de subir estos archivos.

Hice la prueba para que este servicio al finalizar me cree un archivo .txt y lo crea sin problemas. De igual manera que envíe un correo al finalizar la accion definida e igual termina sin problemas.

Comment: ¿cómo ejecutas el exe en el servicio?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path);